# SQL query returns only one value instead of table

Tags: sql, postgresql, python-asyncio

This SQL query on PGadmin works:

```
SELECT name, SUM(revenue) 
FROM users 
GROUP BY name 
HAVING SUM(revenue) != 0 
ORDER BY sum DESC
```

I get a full table, as expected.

However, when I perform

```
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    db = loop.run_until_complete(create_pool())
    class DBCommands:
          pool: Connection = db
    
          REVENUE_RATING = 'SELECT name, SUM(revenue) FROM users GROUP BY name HAVING SUM(revenue) != 0 ORDER BY sum DESC'
            
        async def rating(self):
                command = self.REVENUE_RATING
                rows = await self.pool.fetchval(command)
                logging.info(f'Overall rating table= {rows}')
```

all `db.rating()` returns is the first name and nothing else--no sum of revenues or names of other users--only one value.

What is the problem?

Comment: I'm guessing there is Postgres driver in the mix that you have not told us about. Is it [asyncpg](https://magicstack.github.io/asyncpg/current/usage.html) or something else? If it is `asyncpg` then: `fetchval Run a query and return a value in the first row.`. See here [Cursor](https://magicstack.github.io/asyncpg/current/api/index.html#cursors) for different fetch methods.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Yes, you were right! Thank you! I didn't try this method before, because I have 4 more queries like that with "fetchval" which return me list of results for some reason, I simply copied the approach.

Comment: I doubt you used `fetchval` as the source [fetchval](https://magicstack.github.io/asyncpg/current/_modules/asyncpg/connection.html#Connection.fetchval) is pretty specific: `return data[0][column]`. You sure you where not using just `fetch`?